How is an Einstein Email recommendations block created?
I have watched a thousand videos about Einstein Email Recommendations, read a thousand articles on the subject, but I have not seen any real or fictitious example of how to set up an email with Einstein block (recommended catalog products). I copy and paste the html into the Einstein block, but the images get messed up if I put more than one item. Could someone guide me on how to do it or show me some example or “real” case where I can see how to set up an email with Einstein Email Recommendations? Thanks.

I doubt there are thousand videos and articles written about this, as it indeed is an "under documented" feature of SFMC. However you only need two links to check. This one explains the basics of the block, and as you can see, it is quite simple HTML:
<a href="https://{MID}.recs.igodigital.com/rr/v2/HASH/l/1/%%emailaddr%%">
    <img src="https://{MID}.recs.igodigital.com/rr/v2/HASH/i/1/%%emailaddr%%">
</a>

<a href="https://{MID}.recs.igodigital.com/rr/v2/HASH/l/2/%%emailaddr%%">
    <img src="https://{MID}.recs.igodigital.com/rr/v2/HASH/i/2/%%emailaddr%%">
</a>

You can wrap it in divs, spans or whatever you need, to ensure proper formatting in the email.
Also, here is the most comprehensive and technical overview of this functionality by Jörn Berkefeld.
Between the standard documentation and Jörn's material, you should have everything you need to get going.

Thanks for your answer. It was just a figure of speech. I appreciate your help. Best regards.

@MarcGarcia I figured it out - and was trying to be (little) funny. Please remember to mark my answer as accepted if it was helpful.

hahaha of course. Thank you mate. Really appreciate your help.
